# Running ionic cordova project with --livereload flag Error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I am using ionic 3.20.0, cordova 8.1.2

I'm trying to run the project on the physical device with this command

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload
```

**Note:** it works without --livereload. But if it is included, the app cause to have network error.

Here is the error alert message in the app:

> Application Error: There was a network error.
>   (file:///android_asset/www/+++/http://10.83.8.26:8100

Answer (score -1):

`ionic cordova run android -l -c -live-reload`